# Corrupt tables, how to proceed?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, magento-community

I have a problem with our production database, I think 2 or 3 tables are corrupted. It just came out of nowhere, no major Magento upgrades or big changes made this week, just a few extensions installed.
It is currently not possible to backup the database or create a copy of it (it was possible until one week ago).
My questions are two:
**1) How could have this happened?**
**2) How to proceed? I though about running the Magento database repair, but not having a working backup to make a test first (if not an old one) scares me**

The tables which seem to be corrupted are sales_flat_order_item and sales_flat_order_payment. They're not big at all, less than 10MB in total, around 9k rows.

Comment: did you run mysqlcheck or optimize table? what error it shows?

Answer (score 0):

You can get best result using MySQL Tuner.
Just download, change permission, and execute it.
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl/master/mysqltuner.pl

After that follow instructions as suggestion. It will also advise you for performance boost considering hardware resources available on server.

Thanks,

Comment: Hi, as far as I know the hosting provider run it already and applied the suggested optimizations.